# how can i make a dynamic drop down box in php?

Tags: php, javascript

i need in an php file three drop down boxes or multiple select boxes.

the entries from these boxes are in a mysql database.

the single problem is that the entries in the thrid box depend on the second, and the entries in the second depend on the first.

can someone help? know any examples?

Comment: @AvatarKava: entirely doable without JavaScript. Why JavaScript tag, when OP asked specifically about PHP?

Comment: @EFraim how would you do this *without* Javascript?

Comment: @EFraim: Exactly how are you going to do this without JS? Youd have to use js to load the choices in each successive list based on the choice from the previous list.You could front load all the choices into a JS data structure so you dont have to go back tot he server `onChange` but you still need use js to populate the values.

Comment: @all : For instance as a CSS styled list of links. No need for onchange event. Like ATI driver site did it some time ago.

Comment: @EFraim: But he asked specifically for select/select-multi. Even if they werent important as interface elements themselves hes most likely using them in form so you would still have to grab the value via js for form submit.

Comment: Well @EFraim those aren't "three drop-down boxes", but yes you could set up  a menu-like system with three levels.

Comment: @Ffraim OP is brand new and didn't know how to do this at all so I added the category of the most popular implementation as it was likely to receive quicker assistance.  You could also do this (if no forum submit is required) purely via CSS, requiring a submit after each entry is selected - heck, with iframes or a flash app if you really want - the possibilities are endless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically 3 ways to achieve this:

1. Use JavaScript to `submit()` the form to the server side during `onchange` of the dropdown and let PHP load the options and render the child dropdown accordingly based on the selected dropdown value. Technically the simplest way, but also the least user friendly way. You probably also want to revive all other input values of the form.
2. Let PHP populate all possible child dropdown values in a JavaScript array and use a JavaScript function to fill and display the child dropdown. A little bit trickier, certainly if you don't know JavaScript yet, but this is more user friendly. Only caveat is that this is bandwidth and memory inefficient when you have relatively a lot of dropdown items. Imagine three dropdowns which can each hold 100 items, that would mean a JS array of 100 * 100 * 100 = 1 million items. The page might then grow over 1MB in size.
3. Let JavaScript fire an asynchronous ([ajaxical](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)) HTTP request to the server side and fill and display the child dropdown accordingly. Combines the best of options 1 and 2. Efficient and user friendly. [jQuery](http://jquery.com) is extremely helpful in this since it removes the concerns about crossbrowser compatibility with regard to firing ajaxical requests and traversing the HTML DOM tree. You would otherwise end up with double, triple or even much more of code needed to achieve this.

---

If you let know in a comment or an update of your question which way you would prefer and where exactly you're stucking while implementing the solution, then I'll maybe update the answer to include a basic kickoff example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm from Portugal, so, what we do it's based on Portuguese language, never the less, we've made many working websites and platform's with what you want, please check this link...

if this is what you want, I can send you the code:

> http://www.medipedia.pt/home/home.php?module=farmacia